# finding a node and all of its siblings

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

If an xpath expression locates a node of interest, how can I amend that xpath so that the located node and all sibling nodes are returned?

I'm using selenium, so the version of XPath supported depends on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Its a bit hard without your specific example, but the best way is to select all children of the parent of the node of interest (I assume you mean element nodes in this case). You just use a construction like "/../*". If you post your actual code we can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're selecting the node using a path expression of the form `a/b/c/d[PRED]`, try changing that to `a/b/c[d[PRED]]/*`.